# How to fix lEnqueueNDRangeKernel -4 on a GTX 780 Ti?

Tags: mining

I'm getting `OpenCL Error: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel -4` even though I'm specifying CUDA on an nVidia GTX 780 Ti on Ubuntu 17.04 using the 381.22 drivers. What could be the problem?

```
vadi  ~  Downloads  bin  ./ethminer --cuda --farm-recheck 200 -G -S eu1.ethermine.org:4444 -FS us1.ethermine.org:4444 -O  address
  ℹ  19:22:01|ethminer  Found suitable OpenCL device [ GeForce GTX 780 Ti ] with 3166109696  bytes of GPU memory
  ℹ  19:22:01|ethminer  Connecting to stratum server eu1.ethermine.org:4444
  ℹ  19:22:01|stratum   Connected to stratum server eu1.ethermine.org : 4444
  ℹ  19:22:01|stratum   Starting farm
  ℹ  19:22:01|stratum   Subscribed to stratum server
  ℹ  19:22:01|stratum   Authorized worker d59a78ade291f4e803e766feca6769d243862594.volga
  ℹ  19:22:01|stratum   Received new job #dd6dc396
 cl  19:22:01|cl-0      Set work. Header #dd6dc396… target 0000000112e0
 cl  19:22:01|cl-0      Initialising miner with seed #e7cc04b2…
  m  19:22:01|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:01|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:01|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:02|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:02|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:02|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:02|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:02|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:03|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:03|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
 cl  19:22:03|cl-0      Platform: NVIDIA CUDA
 cl  19:22:03|cl-0      Device:   GeForce GTX 780 Ti  / OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
  m  19:22:03|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
 cl  19:22:03|cl-0      Build info: 

 cl  19:22:03|cl-0      Creating cache buffer
 cl  19:22:03|cl-0      Creating DAG buffer
 cl  19:22:03|cl-0      Loading kernels
 cl  19:22:03|cl-0      Writing cache buffer
 cl  19:22:03|cl-0      Creating buffer for header.
 cl  19:22:03|cl-0      Creating mining buffer
 cl  19:22:03|cl-0      Generating DAG
  ✘  19:22:03|cl-0      clEnqueueNDRangeKernel ( -4 )
  ✘  19:22:03|cl-0      OpenCL Error: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel -4
  m  19:22:03|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:03|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:04|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:04|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:04|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:04|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:04|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:05|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:05|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:05|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:05|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:05|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:06|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:22:06|ethminer  Mining on #dd6dc396… : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the command that your output shows that you used:

> ./ethminer --cuda --farm-recheck 200 -G -S eu1.ethermine.org:4444 -FS us1.ethermine.org:4444 -O  address

According to comments under the following answer, you should not be using the  "-G" option (and therefore OpenCL) but instead use the "-U" option (to use CUDA for NVidia with ethminer executable). Check all of your other parameters and see if they belong to "-G" or whether they belong with "-U" or work for either.

Here are the details:

Under [this Answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/33060/97316) are two comments (second one):

> using the -G flag on ethminer is for OpenCL platforms (AMD cards).
> Because you have NVIDIA hardware (CUDA) you should be using -U
> instead. this could be your issue. It seems to me like you are using
> the CPU and your GPUs aren't doing anything. – Inflexionist Dec 11,
> 2017 at 18:04

Then directly below that, the response (third comment) that confirmed that switching from the "-G" option to the "-U" option started ethminer using his NVidia via CUDA:

> Using - U changed it to cuda. I'm still only at 8mh/s total tho. Gpus
> are sitting at 2100mhz but the power % is only at 30. Driver version
> 385.69. <Memory at 10 500mhz> – Savage300WM Dec 12, 2017 at 0:11

Even after you get CUDA running, you may have to play around to get the best usage. There's no simple one-fits-all recipe to follow, unfortunately.

Upgrade everything to the latest and see if that's best. If not, I saw one solution where downgrading to CUDA 7.0 was the solution, so you may have to do some more research / think outside the box.

You can verify that ethminer can see all your NVidia cards using:

```
ethminer --list-devices
```

Then try benchmarking with this: (and let us know what you found)

```
ethminer -U -M
```

Finally, peruse the "Read Me" at the github repository:

**https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer**